# Java Program Not Starting

Tags: java, jar

I'm currently trying to launch a Java program (JTS3ServerMod, a Java TeamSpeak bot), using the included start script. However, running the start script presents a Java error and I'm not sure why.

I am currently running the Oracle JDK (with JRE) and all of the relative paths and options are in place. Here is the what I see in terminal after the script trys to execute java -jar:

```
[root@s1 JTS3]# ./jts3servermod_startscript.sh start
For security reasons it is prefered not to run the JTS3ServerMod as root!
jts3servermod.pid found, but no JTS3ServerMod running. Possibly your previously started JTS3ServerMod crashed!
Please view the logfile for details.
Starting the JTS3ServerMod...
JTS3ServerMod started, for details please view the log file!
[root@s1 JTS3]# Illegal option: j
Usage: jar {ctxui}[vfmn0PMe] [jar-file] [manifest-file] [entry-point] [-C dir] files ...
Options:
    -c  create new archive
    -t  list table of contents for archive
    -x  extract named (or all) files from archive
    -u  update existing archive
    -v  generate verbose output on standard output
    -f  specify archive file name
    -m  include manifest information from specified manifest file
    -n  perform Pack200 normalization after creating a new archive
    -e  specify application entry point for stand-alone application
        bundled into an executable jar file
    -0  store only; use no ZIP compression
    -P  preserve leading '/' (absolute path) and ".." (parent directory) components from file names
    -M  do not create a manifest file for the entries
    -i  generate index information for the specified jar files
    -C  change to the specified directory and include the following file
If any file is a directory then it is processed recursively.
The manifest file name, the archive file name and the entry point name are
specified in the same order as the 'm', 'f' and 'e' flags.

Example 1: to archive two class files into an archive called classes.jar:
       jar cvf classes.jar Foo.class Bar.class
Example 2: use an existing manifest file 'mymanifest' and archive all the
           files in the foo/ directory into 'classes.jar':
       jar cvfm classes.jar mymanifest -C foo/ .
```

Comment: Please include the script `jts3servermod_startscript.sh` in your question.

Comment: Is the "*Illegal option j*" part of the error output (it's right after the prompt)? Might want to look at that.

Comment: Start with not running it as root user... And `for details please view the log file` sounds important

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, that for some reason, the system started trying to use a version of Java that no longer existed (hence the errors). I simply made the system look in the right place again, and all is well.

Answer (score -1):

I have faced similar problem before I have injected into jar manually did you do something like that by any chance ? you might need to correct the paths in the jar if so